# "Insufficient disk space: ~tmpview.tmp" How to solve?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I currently trying to add some new columns for a view of a LotusNote program. However when I double-click the view of choice, I receive the 'Insufficient disk space' error message.

[image]

The message says .tmp so I assumed that it was referring to my Temp folder, so I cleared it out. I even performed a Disk Cleanup and deleted some emails in my LotusNotes for good measure. *Though I'm not sure if that's even related...*

After all that and still the same issue. Even for my other programs I can open any Views. What other causes do I need to check?

Answer (score 2):

The ~tmpview.tmp is generated in the data-folder of your designer client. Some times it becomes corrupt. Just delete the file, restart your Designer AND Notes Client and it should work again.